# Migrating Chrome USB App API to Web USB API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-app, libusb, webusb

I currently have source code for a Chrome App, but as the platform is being deprecated I need to migrate my API to a Progressive Web Application.

As I still want support for USB in my web platform application, it was suggested that I use the [Web USB API](https://web.dev/usb) to retain functionality, but I can't seem to figure out the equivalent's for the following and how to implement them:

```
chrome.usb.releaseInterface()
chrome.usb.closeDevice()
chrome.usb.claimInterface()
chrome.usb.findDevices()
chrome.usb.bulkTransfer()
```

(Also, I also found there is a [USB Library for Node.JS](https://npmjs.com/package/usb) that works similarly also; is this a good alternative too?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebUSB API provides a `USBDevice` interface which is returned by `navigator.usb.getDevices()` and `navigator.usb.requestDevice()`. This interface has methods equivalent to all but one of those listed above:

```
chrome.usb.releaseInterface() -> releaseInterface()
chrome.usb.closeDevice()      -> close()
chrome.usb.claimInterface()   -> claimInterface()
chrome.usb.bulkTransfer()     -> transferIn() or transferOut().
```

`chrome.usb.findDevices()` is more complex to replace and first requires explaining the differences between the permission model for the WebUSB API and the chrome.usb API. The WebUSB API does not provide an install-time permission to access USB devices. A site must call `navigator.usb.requestDevice()` to ask the user for permission to access new USB devices. For devices with serial numbers permissions are remembered and so you can call `navigator.usb.getDevices()` to get a list of currently connected devices a site previously got permission to access. This is the same model as the `chrome.usb.getUserSelectedDevices()` function. The `chrome.usb.findDevices()` function also implicitly opened the devices in the process of returning them to the application. There is no equivalent to this behavior. The site must explicitly call `open()` on the `USBDevice` interfaces returned by these methods.

Note, that if this application is being deployed into a managed environment the [WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls) policy can be used to mimic the Chrome Apps permission model. Devices allowed by policy will be returned by `navigator.usb.getDevices()` without the need to call `navigator.usb.requestDevice()` and prompt the user first.